# Adapt ASP.NET example for SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

SharePoint restricts the use of C# source code, so I'm wondering how I can get a simple ASP.NET app to work with code behind.

The app is contained in :

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

and the C# class is derived from `System.Web.UI.Page`

I'm thinking I need to make a DLL from the C# code and upload it, but that's just a guess.  (When I try to make a DLL from just the C#, it doesn't recognize the ASP control IDs.)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, the custom code has to be on ANOTHER web site, and you use this code from your ASP/JavaScript on SharePoint.  (Even better approach: Don't use SharePoint!  The complexity is unbelievable.)